# Checking if current element is last element of set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am trying to write a print function for set in C++, and this is what I wrote :

```
void print_set(set<int> &s)
{
    cout<<"{";
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it!=s.end() ; ++it)
    {
        cout<<*it;
        if(it!=(s.end()-1)) //shows error here
            cout<<",";
    }
    cout<<"}";
}
```

But I am getting error. How can I check whether current element is last element or not ?

Comment: always provide the complete unaltered error message.

Comment: You'd think that there's something like a `std::intercalate` algorithm for doing this kind of thing, but I couldn't find anything ready-made...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : Thanks for suggestion, but in this case, error message was too ugly and I thought this would unnecessarily clutter the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest an alternative approach?

Print the comma *before* each element, except the first:

```
void print_set(set<int> &s)
{
    cout << "{";
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it != s.end() ; ++it)
    {
        if(it != s.begin())
            cout << ", ";
        cout << *it;
    }
    cout << "}";
}
```

Comment: Why not exclude the 1st element from loop? Putting an `if` statement just to skip the 1st element looks kinda ugly, at least to me.

Comment: Sure, why not? I'll leave that choice to OP :)

Comment: ok thanks, but it seems from other answers that there is no general approach to this problem i.e. if I want to do some formatting based on second last element, then I can't do that, right ?

Comment: @HappyMittal You can. You can have a counter along the iterators - you know you're at the second to last element when `counter == size-2` (assuming it started from 0).

Answer (score 5):

`set`'s integers are not random-access, so you can't do arithmetic on them. Use `std::prev` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check whether the next element equals the end:

```
auto next = it;
++next;
if (next != s.end())
    cout << ",";
```

Comment: This results in incrementing it, which messes up the loop logic.

Comment: Yeah, the appropriate code would be `auto next = it; ++next;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply the `++` and `--` operators on set iterators. Adding a number is not defined. You can make your code work like so:

```
void print_set(set<int> &s)
{
    cout<<"{";
    auto second_to_last = s.end();
    if (!s.empty()) {
      second_to_last--;
    }
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it!=s.end() ; ++it)
    {
        cout<<*it;
        if(it!=second_to_last) {
            cout<<", ";
        } 
    }
    cout<<"}";
}
```

What this code does is essentially store an iterator to the second to last element once and then compare the element you have with it. Please note that `second_to_last` will not be accurate if the set is empty but the code will still work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this case:

```
void print_set(const std::set<int>& s)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    std::cout << "{";
    for (int e : s)
    {
        std::cout << sep << e;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "}";
}
```